# Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition adb unauthorized after recovery

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, adb

Here is my problem: Lately I had a problem with my BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition that had me reinitialize it to factory settings. Now it works aproperly but I can't use `adb`.

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in the computer, I have done the latest OTA updates on my phone, developer mode is enabled and code protected, I have installed all `phablet-tools` and parametered `~/.android/adb_usb.ini` and `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` according to what I found on the internet (I can post it if you want) but still when I run `adb kill-server && adb devices`, I keep getting:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached 
JU025119    unauthorized
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you get a box on your phone that asks you to authorize the device?

Comment: No, I do not get anything on the phone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing a factory reset adb will be turn off by default. You can change this by using the `--developer-mode` argument with the `ubuntu-device-flash` command. You will also need to provide a password and wipe the device like so:

```
ubuntu-device-flash --channel ubuntu-touch/stable/bq-aquaris.en --wipe --developer-mode --password=password123
```

If you have already factory reset without enabling developer mode you can enable it from the settings app if you go to "About" > "Developer mode" and tap the "Developer Mode" switch. You will need to add a password or pin before you can enable developer mode.

Comment: I hadn't seen your answer when writing mine, thank you for your help :)

Comment: Actually, I just flashed it back and it didn't solve the problem, I still get "unauthorized" and no authorization asked by the phone where I have enabled dev mode and where my screen is unlocked and on the main menu.

Comment: @bsl sometimes I find that I'll need to reconnect the usb cable connecting my laptop & phone. If that doesn't solve it then maybe try restarting adb and/or the phone.